# Referring to GroupName in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In an CFT with a resource - "GroupNamed" in the IAM Policy that refers a variable group name

```
 GroupNamed:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Group"
  Properties:
  GroupName: xyz

 ...

 Effect: Allow
 Action: iam:AddUserToGroup
 Resource: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:group/GroupNamed
```

How do I parameterize the group name?

Below are my attempts but throws malformed policy errors.

1.

```
Resource: !Join ["", ['arn:aws:iam::',!Sub ${AWS::AccountId}, ':group/',!Ref GroupNamed]]
```

2.

```
Resource: !Join ["", ['arn:aws:iam::', !Ref AWS::AccountId, ':group/', !Ref GroupNamed]]
```

3.

```
Resource:
             Fn::Join:
             - ''
             - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
               - Fn::Sub: "${AWS::AccountId}"
               - ":group/"
               - Fn::Ref: GroupNamed
```

> Error: Template validation error: Template Error: Encountered
>   unsupported function: Fn::Ref Supported functions are: [Fn::Base64,
>   Fn::GetAtt, Fn::GetAZs, Fn::ImportValue, Fn::Join, Fn::Split,
>   Fn::FindInMap, Fn::Select, Ref, Fn::Equals, Fn::If, Fn::Not,
>   Condition, Fn::And, Fn::Or, Fn::Contains, Fn::EachMemberEquals,
>   Fn::EachMemberIn, Fn::ValueOf, Fn::ValueOfAll, Fn::RefAll, Fn::Sub,
>   Fn::Cidr]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AWS::IAM::Group documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-group.html) says that ARN is available via *GetAtt*.

For example, this outputs the Group's ARN:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: CloudFormation template for creating lab resources.

Resources:

  GroupNamed:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Group"
    Properties:
      GroupName: xyz

Outputs:
  GroupARN:
    Value: !GetAtt GroupNamed.Arn
```

The output is: `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/xyz`

Therefore, you could just use:

```
Resource: !GetAtt GroupNamed.Arn
```

Comment: Thanks; All though you answered the question; I am still be interested to see how to use nested functions with !Join. Since !Ref gives me the GroupName; can I use !Ref in !Join to get the same result as !GetAtt?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’re passing in a parameter to your stack with the name of GroupName.

Resource: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:group/${GroupName}

Comment: I am referring the group name from a resource @Chris